# deleting option of ubuntu from boot manager

Tags: 12.04

I dual booted windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 using (windows installer for Ubuntu dekstop) on different partitions. i formatted the PARTITION on which Ubuntu was installed and now in boot menu there is still option for Ubuntu. i want to get rid of that. someone help

Answer (score 2):

You need to repair your windows bootloader.To do this,follow the below steps,

- Boot `windows installation disk` then select the `windows repair` or `repair your computer` option before you go into the installation process.
- After selecting windows repair option,it will take you to the next screen.In that screen select the `command prompt` option
- Then run the below commands,on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- This will repair your windows boot files.